# If statement to not show div / h2

Tags: php

This for each / if statement displays changes, and then right below it it displays the changes made.

I am trying to write an if statement that tells it not to show the h2 and the #change_box if there are no changes.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<h2 class="changes"> Changes: </h2>
<div id="change_box">
<? foreach ($audit['Events'] as $event):?>  
<?if ( $event['Type'] != 'Comment'):?>  
<span class="field">
<?= $event['Field']?>
</span>:
<?= $event['Value'] ?>      
<?=($event['Previous'])?>
<?endif?>
<?endforeach?>  
</div>
```

Comment: Wny do you open and close php tags every time? Would be better to make everything in PHP and `echo` whenever you want to print HTML code.

Comment: user2217381: You need to change you coding style. Your code looks quite weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    if ($changes) { // You'll have to set this variable
        //Echo all of your HTML
    else {
        //Echo the stuff you'd rather show if they didn't change anything
    }

?>
```

To give you an idea of how I'd write your code

```
<?php

  if ($changes) {
    echo '<h2 class="changes">Changes:</h2>';
    echo '<div id="change_box">';

    foreach ($audit['Events'] as $event) { 
      if ($event['Type'] != 'Comment') {
        echo $event['Field'] . </span> . $event['Value'] . $event['Previous'];
      }   
    }

    echo "</div>"
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please make space after each `<?` and make sure you enabled short tags

```
  <?php if(is_array($audit['Events']) && $audit['Events']):?>
  <h2 class="changes"> Changes: </h2>
  <div id="change_box">
  <?php foreach ($audit['Events'] as $event):?>  
     <?php if ( $event['Type'] != 'Comment'):?>  
        <span class="field">
        <?php echo $event['Field'];?>
        </span>:
        <?php echo $event['Value']; ?>      
        <?php echo $event['Previous'];?>
     <?php endif;?>
  <?php endforeach;endif;?>  
 </div>
```

Comment: its best practice to never use short tags

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your code with an `if` like

```
if(count($audit['Events'])>0)
{

//Your code

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to take away a div like if ($audit['Events'] =Null) take away #change_box or something?

Answer (score 0):

Wny do you open and close php tags every time? Would be better to make everything in PHP and echo whenever you want to print HTML code.

```
<?php
echo "<h2 class=\"changes\"> Changes: </h2>";
echo "<div id=\"change_box\">";

foreach ($audit['Events'] as $event) {
    if ( $event['Type'] != 'Comment') {
        echo "<span class=\"field\">".$event['Field']."</span>";
        echo $event['Value'];
        echo "(".$event['Previous'] .")";
    }
}

echo "</div>";
?>
```